# Error generated Hibernate Jpa Repository Query

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

I use this query with Jpa Repository:

```
@Query("select f.attrezzature from FoglioLavoro f where f.id = :idFoglioLavoro")
Page<AbstractAttrezzatura> findAttrezzaturaFoglioLavoro(@Param("idFoglioLavoro")Long idFoglioLavoro, Pageable pageable);
```

But when I use this query I obtain this error:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as col_0_0_ from foglio_lavoro fogliolavo0_, foglio_lavoro_attrezzature attrez' at line 1
```

And this is the generated spring-data query:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    count(.) as col_0_0_ 
from
    foglio_lavoro fogliolavo0_,
    foglio_lavoro_attrezzature attrezzatu1_,
    abstract_attrezzatura abstractat2_ 
where
    fogliolavo0_.id=attrezzatu1_.fogli_lavoro 
    and attrezzatu1_.attrezzature=abstractat2_.id 
    and fogliolavo0_.id=?
```

How can I solve it??
Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your repository method returns `Page<T>`, Spring Data JPA tries to infer a query for total count of elements from the query you specified, and sometimes the inferred query is wrong.

In such a case you need to specify a count query explicitly:

```
@Query(
    value = "select f.attrezzature from FoglioLavoro f where f.id = :idFoglioLavoro",
    countQuery = "select count(elements(f.attrezzature)) from FoglioLavoro f where f.id = :idFoglioLavoro")
Page<AbstractAttrezzatura> findAttrezzaturaFoglioLavoro(@Param("idFoglioLavoro")Long idFoglioLavoro, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this: "select count(f.attrezature) .... "?? Where attrezzature is a property of f....

Comment: Thanks for correction, I didn't noticed that you need to count `f.attrezzature`

Comment: Thanks, the post saved my time!